# OpenShift CLI: oc vs rhc?

Tags: openshift

What is the difference between **rhc** and **oc** CLI-tools?

As I see, they do almost the same:

**oc**:

> The OpenShift CLI exposes commands for managing your applications, as
>   well as lower level tools to interact with each component of your
>   system.

**rhc** does the same, no?

What should I use to manage my containers on OpenShift platform?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `rhc` tool is for OpenShift 2. The `oc` tool is for OpenShift 3. They are completely different versions of the package. So you need to know which version of OpenShift you are using. If you are using the existing OpenShift Online version it is version 2. If you are using the new OpenShift Online developer preview, it is version 3.

Comment: I'm using OpenShift PaaS, so I should use rhc, right?

Comment: If you are logging in via openshift.com, and didn't request access to the 'OPENSHIFT ONLINE (NEXT GEN) DEVELOPER PREVIEW', then it is OpenShift 2.